# Bubble sort explanation in parallel programming

Tags: algorithm, sorting, parallel-processing

I was searching for parallel programming  algorithm for bubble sort.I understood the process but didn't get idea .How is it working ? How do process id or label id(used for each process) deal with the swapping index and how did it solve the issue with sequential programming in sorting?I am mentioning the algorithm for it from a famous site given below.Thanks in advance.

```
procedure ODD-EVEN_PAR (n) 

begin 
id := process's label 
for i := 1 to n do 

 begin 
  if i is odd and id is odd then 
     compare-exchange_min(id + 1); 
  else 
     compare-exchange_max(id - 1);

  if i is even and id is even then 
     compare-exchange_min(id + 1); 
  else 
     compare-exchange_max(id - 1);

end for

end ODD-EVEN_PAR
```

Comment: I assume the `else` is for the second part of the condition `id is odd` and `id is even` only? And the parameter to `compare_exchange_min` and `..._max` is `i + 1` or `i - 1` instead of `id + 1` and `id - 1`?

Comment: why should the process id and i be even at same time and both  odd at same time and why same not.

Comment: As it is, `compare-exchange_max(id - 1)` will be executed twice if either `i` or `id` is odd.

Comment: @m69 can you explain me how the algorithm is working.

Comment: This site has code for sequential and parallel odd-even-transposition sort: http://parallelcomp.uw.hu/ch09lev1sec3.html The `else` is indeed only for the second condition, but the `id + 1` is correct.

Comment: Questions on SO about odd-even-transposition sort:  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=odd+even+transposition+sort